# pandas MonthOffset doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure whether this is a bug, but `pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset()` seems to deliver a wrong result. It increases day instead of month.

```
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Timestamp('2015-07-15')
print(ts)

2015-07-15 00:00:00


ts1 = ts + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset(1)
print(ts1)

2015-07-16 00:00:00
```

Comment: I can confirm. Same result here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in [Issue 7707](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7707) -

> you need to specify month=1 and it will work
>   (it's interpreting the first arg as the day keyword)

You need to specify the `months` keyword argument.

Example -

```
ts1 = ts + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset(months=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you specify the offset value with the arguments months=1, it should work.

```
     ts1 = ts + pd.tseries.offsets.MonthOffset(months=1)
     print(ts1)
```

Comment: This does work, but it seems like it ought to assume you mean months in a function called `MonthOffset`!